# Typescript - Force default type for additional properties in interface

Tags: typescript

I have an interface which has a few properties with certain types

```
interface dummyInterface {
    propA: string,
    propB: boolean,
    propC: number,
}
```

Props A through C are mandatory, but objects of this type can also include any number of additional properties with any name. However, I would like to force all additional properties to be of type `string`. I know it can't be done by adding something like

```
{
    .
    .
    .
    [additionalProp: string]: string
}
```

since this would contradict `PropB` and `PropC` which are `boolean` and `number` respectively.

Is there any way in which I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with type intersection:

```
interface MandatoryProps {
    numberProp: number;
    boolProp: boolean;
}

type TypeWithMandatoryAndOptionalProps =
    // For mandatory props:
    MandatoryProps &
    // For optionals:
    Record<string, string>;

declare const foo: TypeWithMandatoryAndOptionalProps;

foo.blablabla; // string
foo.numberProp; // number
foo.boolProp; // boolean
```

**UPD**. I think I've rushed a bit with the answer. Whereas suggested type seems to solve the issue with *defining* such a type, there's still a bunch of issues with using it (explained by TS maintainers in the issue linked in comments below). You can try to solve the issue with assigning a value to a variable with such a type by casting through `any` or using `Object.assign`:

```
const foo = <TypeWithMandatoryAndOptionalProps><any>{/* ... */};

// or

const bar: TypeWithMandatoryAndOptionalProps = Object.assign(
   { numberProp: 1, boolProp: false },
   { blablabla: 'test' }
);
```

But both of those options basically *tricks* type checker rather than providing a sound type system for your program.

TL;DR of that would be as follows. Unless you're trying to get type working an existing JS program, just rethink your types. Use separate property for object with key signature or a `Map`.

Thanks @jcalz for pointing to TS issue.

Comment: No, this still produces an error: `Property 'numberProp' is incompatible with index signature. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: I've checked the code with TS playground. Where have you put index signature? Note that the interface *does not* have it. Also what version of TS are you using?

Comment: I suspect @DanielR is having a problem like this: `const foo2: TypeWithMandatoryAndOptionalProps = {
  boolProp: true,
  numberProp: 3
}`.  There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) surrounding this problem, so maybe @KirillDmitrenko can mention this in the answer.

Comment: @jcalz Yep, looks like it. Thanks for the issue link, updated the answer.